# How do I run a docker container as a privileged user with user namespaces

Tags: docker, containers, docker-machine, linux-containers

I am running with user namespaces enabled and I need to run a particular container as a root user (the container needs to be able to execute the Linux mount command from inside).

How do I run a specific container in privileged mode when namespaces are enabled?

Comment: By default a container is run as root without having to elevate privileges ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer... set `--userns host` on the docker run command